Puppeteer clicking Reddit login button
I'm running into trouble with Puppeteer with selecting a button during a login process. I'm trying to have it log in to Reddit but the login button has no name or ID and there are other buttons that might get selected. It's also wrapped in other elements so I'm not even sure which one to select. I'll include my code below. Does anyone know what I can do to press the login button on Reddit.com after it enters the username and password? Selecting the other elements was easy because they have ids.
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function loginToReddit(usernameText, passwordText){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: false,
        userDataDir: "./tmp"
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.reddit.com/');
    await page.click('#login-button');

    sleep(2000).then(() => {
        enterCredentials(usernameText, passwordText, page);
    });
}

async function enterCredentials(usernameText, passwordText, page){
    await page.click('#login-username');
    await page.keyboard.type(usernameText,{
        delay: 50,
    });
    await page.click('#login-password');
    await page.keyboard.type(passwordText,{
        delay: 50,
    });
    sleep(2000).then(() => {
        selectLoginButton(page);
    });
}

async function selectLoginButton(page) {
    page.waitForNavigation();
    //const xp = 'faceplate-tracker button';
    const xp = 'faceplate-tracker > button';
    const el = await page.waitForSelector(xp);
    await el.click();
}

loginToReddit('username', 'password');


sleep(2000).then(() => { is outside your promise chain. Use await all the way through. page.waitForNavigation(); was never awaited. sleep is built into node already: import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises". I suggest working on async/await promise basics and avoid sleeping. The login button unambiguously has an id #login-button so it should be easy to click if you fix your other issues.

Be aware Reddit is using the shadow DOM, which prevents selectors from working. I'd recommend looking into the "pierce selector."  A terrific link I found: https://medium.com/@carlosabpreciado/scraping-the-shadow-dom-with-puppeteer-9f8f41d998e8

@ggorlen I'll look more into promises because the sleep is the only way I could get the process to delay long enough without saying #login-username and #login-password weren't found. #login-button isn't the correct ID though. That id only opens the login prompt. I need to click the login button on the login pop-up window. Still trying to find a way to identify that one. My code is able to open the login window and type, I just can't submit it.

@ggorlen I was able to remove the sleep methods with page.waitForSelector. Now I just need to identify the button on the login popup which submits the credentials. Since it doesn't have a name or id to identify it I was trying to use xpath but I don't think Puppeteer supports that in the current version and my attempts have been unsuccessful. I also see action="click" on the <faceplate-tracker> tag so I'm wondering if I need to select that element.

<button rpl="" class="login w-100 button-large px-[var(--rem14)] button-brand items-center justify-center button inline-flex " type="button"><span class="flex items-center justify-center"><span class="flex items-center gap-xs">Log In</span></span></button> This is the full tag for the specific button I need to click. There's plenty of detail but nothing page.click() or page.evaluate() can use to identify it.

Did you try await page.keyboard.press("Enter")?

Before going further with Puppeteer, I suggest brushing up on your promise basics. The code here doesn't make a lot of sense in a few places. Don't mix then and await and make sure to await all promises. page.waitForNavigation(); without an await doesn't do anything.
Also avoid premature abstractions--these extra functions just make it more difficult to get things correct. Once you have working code, then you can factor it out.
Avoid sleeps. Use precise predicates.
Note that the page has a number of shadow roots, so I suggest reading about that and using the >>> selector.
Back to the main question, you can simply press Enter instead of clicking the login button:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^23.6.0

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.locator("#login-button").click();
  const un = await page.waitForSelector("#login-username");
  await un.type("foo");
  await page.type("#login-password", "baz");

  for (let tries = 0; tries < 100; tries++) {
    try {
      await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

      // just for this demo; use some other
      // 'success' selector for the actual automation
      await page.waitForSelector(
        ">>> ::-p-text(Invalid username or password)",
        {timeout: 100}
      );
      break;
    } catch {
      //
    }
  }

  await page.screenshot({path: "proof.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Normally, it won't be this tricky, but pressing Enter immediately after typing doesn't submit the form (while validation runs), so I opted to retry until the key press works. Maybe not the best solution but sufficient for starters.
If this seems too verbose, you can replace the for loop with a couple-second sleep before pressing Enter, but that's not best practice. If you must use a timeout, use this syntax rather than .then:
import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";

// ...
await setTimeout(3000);

